# Hierarchical directory structure in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to creating dropbox like web application. I want user to create directory and upload files to server. I have completed most of the task but i am stuck with the question "how to efficiently store the directory structure in the database?".

Project requirements: 
1) It should be able to store directories in a way that given the path of particular directory, it should be able to find out all the files and directories inside it.
For eg: given path: root/abc/xyz, I should be able to find all the files and directories under xyz.
2) Two directories inside different parent directories can have same name

My Research on internet: 
1)There is a method called path enumeration wherein application would store entire path to directory in the column corresponding to that directory
For eg: if i have directory structure as root/abc/xyz
then row in table corresponding to xyz directory will store path root/abc
but this method doesnt seems efficient
2) I also got information on nested set model. But depth of the tree and total number of hierarchical nodes are unknown so it can't be used
3) There is another method in which i only store root_directory id instead of entire path in each directory entry
for eg: create table directory(directory_id varchar(32) primary key, directory_name varchar(128),created_date varchar(20), root_directory varchar(32),user_id varchar(32))
But how can i query the database using path as root/abc/xyz to to get all the files and directories under xyz directory. I found some multiple join operation to perform so. But join queries will affect the performance badly as the depth of directory structure increases

Please can anyone show me a way to better solution. I would be thankful to you

Comment: An closure table would be very nice to use    easy to update  easy to insert and easy to query.. googling on "closure table mysql" or "closure table" should give you the information you need.

Comment: Eh? That's EXACTLY when you WOULD use nested set!?!?!

Comment: nested sets or modified preorder list what is what you mean @Strawberry these structures makes it harder to insert, update or query.. closure table is almost the same but makes it more easier to work with.. http://karwin.blogspot.nl/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html

Comment: i think i didn't understood the concept of nested query well. Thanks for your answer. Please can anyone give me overview of nested set

Comment: Google is your friend. Hillyer's article is pretty much the definitive guide.

Comment: i searched and got good tutorial on internet. But nested set model require each node to be unique. In my situtaion i need to get all child directories and files if path is specified. And path can be like
root/abc/xyz/abc ie. two directory having same name